# Cloud Firestore indexes for collection groups with multiple where clauses

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

I have written a function that runs every x amount of time and changes a field in a document in cloud firestore if a specific condition applies. However, the function fails due to the function needing an index. I don't know what index I need.

This is the line that gives the error.

```
const snapshot = db.collectionGroup('people').where('dateEndFunctional', '<', today).where('state', '==', 'active').get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
```

This is the error message I'm getting

```
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/fmis-online-dev/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ck5wcm9qZWN0cy9mbWlzLW9ubGluZS1kZXYvZGF0YWJhc2VzLyhkZWZhdWx0KS9jb2xsZWN0aW9uR3JvdXBzL3Blb3BsZS9pbmRleGVzL18QAhoJCgVzdGF0ZRABGhUKEWRhdGVFbmRGdW5jdGlvbmFsEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ
```

If I follow the link, I always get an error, like the image below.
[image]
It states:
Loading failed.
An error occured while loading [link]. Try again.

However, eery time I try again, it gives the same error.

I have tried to create a combined index for both of the fields the where clauses are testing, as well as creating two seperate indexes for each of the fields. Both resulted in the same error. What index do I need for this function to properly work?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What error do you get when you follow the link? The link is meant to create an index for you. Otherwise you can do it manually, you need to create a CollectionGroup index on the `people` collection for these 2 fields

Comment: that link is a shortcut to create your index, what error are you getting?

Comment: Like I stated, I have tried to create a collectionGroup index for both fields on their own, as well as a combined collectionGroup index. Could you please clarify what index I exactly need and how I should create it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added a picture and translation of the error message

Comment: Are you logged into the Firebase console?

Comment: :O I was logged into the wrong google cloud account, which made the project referenced in the url not show up. I switched accounts and it is fixed now.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link should work, just make sure you are logged into the right account on google cloud.....

For the people that want the answer:
A collection group index on people with state ASC and dateEndFunctional ASC
[image]

I don't know why it didn't work before, because I think I have tried this. Perhaps the order of fields matter. The link should take care of that